# How to slide element in jQuery replaceWith?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this in my jquery response:

```
...
      success: function(data) {
        $(".headline").replaceWith(function() {
          return $(data).hide().fadeIn();
      });
```

Where `data` is like: `<h3 id="5" class="headline-content">Some headline </h3>`
I'm wondering how can I slide the data so that it appear that it enters from the left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses JQuery and JQuery UI (for the slide left effect).  Here, `function test(data)` would be your success function. `replaceWith` is not necessary.

```js
var d = "<h3>Some headline </h3>";
test(d);

function test(data) {
    // Inject the result into the DOM element, but hide it at the same time
    $(".headline").hide().html(data);

    // toggle the visibility and animate the element coming in from the right
    $(".headline").toggle( "slide", {direction: "right"});
}
```

```css
.headline { font-size:2em; 
    width: 300px;
    height: 2em;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" 
         src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="headline"></div>
```

Comment: Well this causes the initial text to disappear. Also, I really prefer not to use ~250KB jquery-ui.js just to have this slider. Isn't there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @Karlom The text doesn't have to disappear. Just remove the `.hide()` instruction. I just thought that this was what you were looking for. And, you don't have to use JQuery UI, but writing your own slide may be more trouble than it's worth.